# How to build a multiMatchQuery with BoolQueryBuilder

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I would like to search fields with ElasticSearch using multiMatchQuery. This is my code:

```
    private BoolQueryBuilder addSearchQuery(BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder, String search) {
        String[] searchArray= {"fieldA", "fieldB"};

        QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery(search, searchArray).operator(Operator.AND);

        return QueryBuilders.boolQuery();

    }
```

It should be a search across `fieldA` and `fieldB`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Usually, an AND operator needs *all* parts to succeed (translation: the value needs to be in both columns). Try an OR operator

Answer (score 0):

```
private BoolQueryBuilder addSearchQuery(BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder, String search) {
        String[] searchArray= ["fieldA", "fieldB"];
        return boolQueryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders. multiMatchQuery(search, Arrays.asList(searchArray).operator(Operator.AND));
    }
```

Instead of declaring it as an array, you can directly create a list and pass it. Since you had array in the code, I modified that.

Comment: not works :( i use JDK12. i get a empty Result List

Comment: Can you print the query in console and run it directly in kibhana and see whats the result you are getting